# Error when converting JSON to Dataset in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using JSON.Net to retrieve the following JSON formatted data.

> {"Pagination":{"CurrentPage":1,"PageSize":20,"NumberOfPages":3796,"totalCount":75913},"Data":[{"SalesOrderNumber":"003119"},{"SalesOrderNumber":"003336"},{"SalesOrderNumber":"003410"},{"SalesOrderNumber":"003520"}]}

I can successfully retrieve the data and load it into a C# textbox.  What I want to do is load it into a dataset.  I'm using the following statement to try and load the dataset.

```
DataSet dsSalesOrders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(response.Content);
```

When I run the program I get the following error

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path 'Pagination', line 1, position 15.'

As this is my first time using JSON how do I fix this??

Thanks

Comment: i'd create a custom class for that information.

Comment: It's not a flat row/column structure, so I'm not sure what you think the expected result would be if you were able to put it into a table? You need to deserialise it to a type (or set of types) which actually match the structure of the JSON. A tool like http://json2csharp.com/ will actually create them for you (usually very accurately) if you paste in the JSON

Comment: Using a DataSet/DataTable/DataView should be done sparingly - it's often used as a leaky abstraction for representing information. They have their uses, but they're abused far too often. Most of the time it's better to define classes that represent the information that you need to pass around.

Comment: This is not a valid format for DataSet, its quite particular. You can create a wrapper for the data,, or a custom type for the object to deserialize into. You'll most likely want to do that latter, and then you can implement any methods you would need to format the data into whatever you're trying to load this into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this class as receiving class

```
public class YourMainObject
{
    public Pagination Pagination { get; set; }
    public Datum[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Pagination
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public int totalCount { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize to this, then populate the dataset separately.

PS: On the discussion below, fellow programmers are suggesting that you might not really need to use a DataSet

Comment: "then populate the dataset separately" you mean skip the DataSet entirely?

Comment: @mason I don't know what it's the purpose of him using the DataSet, but it might be that he needs it to use ADO.NET capabilities or something, so an extra passage to an object should avoid errors on objects you don't have full control on. So he can deserialize to a custom object, then populate the dataset with data

Comment: It's far more likely the DataSet isn't necessary for whatever the use case is, given how few the valid uses are. I just don't want your answer to give the false impression that a DataSet is somehow a necessary part of the solution.

Comment: You can use UDTs with ADO.NET.

Comment: It is part of the solution, as the user is specifically asking to use a dataset. If he asked "Is dataset ok or can I do it differently?" then you would have a point. Anyway if he realize he doesn't need a dataset, well, I don't know lol

Comment: Looks like its only available for SQL Server, but theres some documentation for it, though it isnt very good [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/accessing-user-defined-types-retrieving-udt-data?view=sql-server-2017). Now I'm starting to wonder if he needs ADO at all since he is loading json from what I assume is a REST service.

Comment: @TheBatman I've used them in SQL server, but I was returning them through Entity Framework, which mapped them to objects automatically. Then I served them with an API. Never knew they were available on ADO.NET, on code side

Comment: @LiquidCore Just because the OP asked about a Dataset doesn't mean they actually need one. Maybe they just made an incorrect assumption. I see questions with these kinds of misplaced assumptions built into them all the time. I agree with Batman, I can't see how it would help to involve a dataset...in the context of the data structure shown, it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Liquid Core

Thanks for the class definitions, that is what I was looking for.

As for the discussion of my dataset comment, they are correct I don't need a dataset.  I mostly work with SQL data so I'm used to using datasets in WinForms projects for presenting my data.  Once I got my Dataum class loaded I just assigned the datasource to the array.